Transformers: AutoModel from pretrained istantiation error
I'm instantiating a CodeBert Model using AutoModel.fromPretrained.
File "/public.hpc/codeBertConcat/./codeBertConcatEvaluation.py", line 278, in <module>
    model = CodeBERTConcatenatedClass(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES).to(DEVICE)
  File "/public.hpc/codeBertConcat/./codeBertConcatEvaluation.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.codebert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('microsoft/codebert-base', cache_dir="./cache2")
  File "/public.hpc/codeBertConcat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 493, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "/public.hpc/codeBertConcat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2903, in from_pretrained
    ) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
  File "/public.hpc/codeBertConcat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3061, in _load_pretrained_model
    id_tensor = id_tensor_storage(tensor) if tensor.device != torch.device("meta") else id(tensor)
RuntimeError: Expected one of cpu, cuda, xpu, mkldnn, opengl, opencl, ideep, hip, msnpu, xla, vulkan device type at start of device string: meta

Someone has a clue?
I'm using Transformers version 4.31.0 and PyTorch 1.8.1+cu111

Can you please add the line of code you are calling exactly? I want to see all the parameters.

Please check your computer supporting the GPU or using gpu first.
then If you do not resolve the problem, upgrade pytorch version newest.
your pytorch version is 1.8.1, current latest pytorch version is 2.3.0.
pytorch homepage
